# change initial pose of camera in rgbdslam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, octomap, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am looking to mount the kinect on a robot and it will be tilted at about 45 degrees towards the floor. I want to add the inital offset of 45 degree to the initial pose of the camera. Would like to know which part of the code should I look at?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62742/change-initial-pose-of-camera-in-rgbdslam/) by [VicL](https://answers.ros.org/users/4835/vicl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the method firstNode in graph_manager.cpp. You can change the member init_base_pose_ there according to your needs.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2